# PHP Display The Array Index of Object

Tags: php, arrays, object

Following code

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach($this->allcategories as $k){
    var_dump($k);
}
```

is displaying

```
object(Application_Model_Categories {
    ["_data":"Application_Model_Base":private]=> array(7) { 
        ["CategoriesName"]=> string(8) "Clothing"
    }
}
```

but I need just the **CategoriesName** i.e **Clothing**, nothing else.

Comment: I need to display CategoriesName, the array index of object Application_Model_Categories["_data":"Application_Model_Base":private].

Comment: _data is private so you can't access it from outside

Comment: I have the model and controller access, so what code should I write in controller/model/view?

Comment: can u share the code for Application_Model_Base?

Comment: @user3278995 try adding a public function is your class. I have added the code for you below

Comment: Thanks a lot, I convert the access modifier from private to public and it worked for me. How can I make your answer right for me on stackoverflow?

Comment: This question is not about Zend Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this in your class

```
public function getX(){
    return $this->_data;
}
```

And call this from where you want the data.

```
$data = $this->getX();
echo $data["CategoriesName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should only print "Clothing":

```
foreach($this->allcategories as $k){
    $cat = $k['CategoriesName']; 
    var_dump($cat);
}
```